FLUJO POWER AUTOMATE: ¿COMO INSERTAR UNA IMAGEN EN EL CUERPO DE UN CORREO ELECTRONICO?
Tras buscar información (mucha) al respecto de esto por todas partes, ninguna de las opciones me funcionaba bien. Así que cogiendo ideas de aquí y de allá he conseguido hacer esto para resolver el problema. Lo publico por si puede ser útil a alguien.
En PowerAutomate, hemos creado un flujo para envío de correos. El flujo se inicia desde un Microsoft form, Los correos pueden llevar una imagen embebida en el cuerpo de un correo. Estas imágenes las carga el usuario desde el formulario:
Una vez que la respuesta llega al flujo, los pasos a seguir son:

Obtenemos los detalles de la respuesta desde el formulario


Declaramos 2 variables tipo array, “ImagenesForm” e “ImagenesMail”



En “ImagenesForm” se recogerán las imágenes incluidas en la respuesta del usuario, asignándole el valor correspondiente de las salidas de la acción “Obtener los detalles de la respuesta” parseado como json


Se recorre el array “ImagenesForm” a través de una acción “Aplicar a cada uno” a la que llamamos “RecorrerImagenesForm”


En este recorrido obtenemos el nombre de cada imagen y su contenido

•   Agregamos un elemento a la matriz ImagenesMail

Para cada elemento que se añade, le asignamos la propiedad Name, con el valor de la variable ImgNombre, y la propiedad ContentBytes, con el valor que se obtiene de la acción “Obtener contenido de archivo mediante ruta de acceso”

Ahora recorremos el  array “ImagenesMail” a través de una acción “Aplicar a cada uno” a la que llamamos “RecorrerImagenesMail”

•   Obtenemos el contenido y el tipo de contenido

•   Y, por último, creamos una etiqueta HTML de imagen para cada una de las imágenes

El valor de esta variable será el de una etiqueta html
Si necesitamos insertar más de una imagen, podemos crear una nueva variable matriz, en la que iremos incluyendo todas y cada una de las etiquetas html generadas en el paso anterior.
Posteriormente, para mostrarlas en el cuerpo del correo solo habría que recorrer ese array, concatenar las etiquetas en una variable string y mostrar cada etiqueta a conveniencia en el cuerpo del correo:
Espero que sea útil a alguien

Te recomiendo empezar por leer [ask] y hacer el [tour]. Hacer una pregunta y responderla tu misma es una práctica bienvenida en SO, pero DEBES seguir el FORMATO del sitio!! No somos un foro, somos un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. Usa el enlace [edit] y deja esto como una pregunta REAL, simplemente planteando el problema (lo más detallado posible) y luego añades una RESPUESTA en la parte de abajo, ahí donde pone Tu Respuesta con, exactamente, la respuesta!! Por cierto, edita también el título y quita todas las mayúsculas que sobran. Solo la primera letra debe ir en mayúsculas.
